# Creating database in Azure databricks on External Blob Storage giving error

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-connect

I have mapped my blob storage to `dbfs:/mnt/`  under name `/mnt/deltalake`
and blob storage container name is deltalake.

Mounting to Dbfs is done using Azure KeyVault backed secret scope.

When  I try to create a  database using `CREATE DATABASE abc` with location `'/mnt/deltalake/databases/abc'`   this errors out saying path does not exist.

However when I was using the dbfs path as storage by using .. `CREATE DATABASE abc` with location `'/user/hive/warehouse/databases/abc'`  .. it was always successful.

Wonder what is going wrong .
Suggestions please.

Answer (score 0):

Using a mount point, you should be able to access existing files or write new files through databricks.

However, I believe the SQL commands, such as CREATE DATABASE, only work on the underlying hive metastore.

You may need to create a database for your blob storage outside of databricks, and then connect to the database to read and write from it using databricks.

Comment: Got this resolved. The mounting was not done properly. Otherwise all is good as expected.

Comment: You should post how you resolved this as an answer so others can see in the future